# How to plot following data:

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I have data in the following csv table. It is quite tricky to plot in python though.  I could remove some header lines manually and then plot some data vs. time, but the time is in string format and separated in minutes and hours...

I tried to select the first column of the data after I removed header lines, but received an `unhashable type: slice` error message.

If I had time data separated out, I could use this kind of piece of code:

```
def get_sec(time_str):
    h, m, s = time_str.split(':')
    return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60 + float(s)
```

Once I have all the data in an array (matrix), then from that point on, I can create a plot using:

```
plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1],'r',data[:,0],data[:,2],...
```

If I could have headers handled automatically, it would be better but that's not a big deal. Here is some of the data:

```
00:00:00.000  0.002  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.04    7.74   160.44
00:00:00.008  0.001  0.003    0.003  7.74  8.34    8.04  160.245   
00:00:00.016  0.001  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.34    7.74  160.065   
00:00:00.024  0.002  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.04    7.74  160.245   
00:00:00.032  0.001  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.04    8.04  159.705   
00:00:00.040  0.002  0.003    0.002  7.44  8.04    8.04  160.245
```

Comment: Your print screen is a blank screenshot; it would probably be helpful to see.

Comment: OK cool. So have you Googled how to use the python CSV module to pull data from a CSV? You will want to create a CSV reader object, iterate through it, and load all the data from it into a matrix or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is saved in a file which looks like this

```
time colA colB colC colD valueA valueB valueC
00:00:00.000  0.002  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.04    7.74   160.44
00:00:01.008  0.001  0.003    0.003  7.74  8.34    8.04  160.245   
00:00:02.016  0.001  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.34    7.74  160.065   
00:00:03.024  0.002  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.04    7.74  160.245   
00:00:04.032  0.001  0.003    0.002  7.74  8.04    8.04  159.705   
00:00:05.040  0.002  0.003    0.002  7.44  8.04    8.04  160.245
```

you can read in  your data using **pandas** and plot it with matplotlib as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fn = "data/timetable.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(fn,delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=True )
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format="%H:%M:%S.%f")

plt.plot(df["time"], df["valueA"])
plt.plot(df["time"], df["valueB"])

plt.show()
```

[image]